# Add a Class in jsp

Tags: java, apache, class, jsp, tomcat

I'm working in a JSP page which is the following:

```
<%@page import="java.util.*" %> 


<%
 String[] colors = {"Gray", "Brown", "Red" , "Orange", "yellow", "Green", "Blue", "purple"};
 String color, numero;

 color=request.getParameter("colores");
 numero=request.getParameter("numeros");

 int c = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("colores")); 
 int num = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("numeros"));

%>

<HTML>


  <BODY>  

    <TABLE BORDER="1" align="center" bgcolor="#E8FDFF" height="40%">

     <TR>
     <TD bgcolor="<%=colors[c-1] %>"> 


    <% HERE GOES THE JAVA PART %>


     </TD>
     </TR>


    </TABLE>

  </BODY>

</HTML>
```

I'd like to add a java class and method just like the following:

```
public class Tabla 
{
public static void main (String[] args) 
    {        
        int n=67;       
        int j;

        Tabla table = new Tabla ();
        int dato[];
        dato=table.producto(n);        

        for (j=0;j<10;j++)
        {System.out.println(dato[j]);
        }

    }



    public int [] producto(int num) 
    { 
        // make a 10-element array
        int a[] = new int[10];

       // fill up the array with products
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {a[i] = num * (i+1); }

        return a;        

    }    


}
```

I've tried adding the whole code to the jsp page but it doesn't work. I do not have any idea how to do it.

I've "googled" for the solution and people talk about a class folders. I found that class folder in my PC for Apache Tomcat which is the sw I am using but the class files are kind of "coded" so I guess I am not doing the right thing.

Any suggestion or idea of what I can do would be very aprreciated

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I looked up and my problem is how to add the java class to the jsp page?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsp/info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use `main()` method in a web application so simply no luck to put your class with `main()` method in jsp page. Other way you can try any of these two things:

- Write a simple bean class, place your code there in the form of public methods,import that class in your jsp and create that class object by using `<jsp:useBean >` tag set properties to that class object by using `<jsp:setProperty >` and simply call the methods over that object according to your requirement.
- Create a jsp page that have just some view part of your application, take `<form > tag` in your jsp, take a servlet and map it with url pattern, use this servlet's url in form tag as action value, like this send the control to a servlet, put your logic in servlet's `doGet(-,-)` or `doPost(-,-)` method to execute your logic.

Comment: With the first solution (Write a simple bean class) how can you import the class to the jsp's project folder? Do you just simply drag the class file generated by Netbeans into your jsp project folder? 
Thanks again

Comment: Exactly no, 

1) Put your bean class in a package(not mendatory but recommended) in classes folder of your project.
2)  Now to import this class write <%@ page import="p1.MyBean" %> at the top of your jsp page
3) After importing that class to create object of that class use <jsp:useBean >..For more info see here: http://www.java2all.com/1/2/8/84/Technology/JSP/JSP-Elements/JSP-Standard-Action-elements